# What would not be enjoyable about being a bird or having wings?

Tags: avian

This is for a screen play I'm writing.  Basically, one character spots a bird and wonders what it'd be like to fly.  The second character has the power to access other people's senses so she subtly does this to the bird.  I was thinking maybe I could put that it would be rubbish to be a bird because you have to leave your kids alone but I was just wondering if there is anything that would be more annoying about being a bird.

Comment: If we get reincarnated and I can't come back as human I want to come bach as a bird. Can't decide between a house sparrow (for the sex) or a crow or parrot (for the brain).

Comment: Is this from the _perspective_ of the bird? because the bird might not give a damn about its young, and think it a relief. Other then that, I would think that the physical exertion would be the main issue, and flying itself to just be 'meh' from the birds perspective. if its from the perspective of a human that flies, its a complete opinion question.

Comment: @marky I have observed a pair of blackbirds attacking a fox that was trying to plunder their nest. You could be in no doubt that they cared as much as any human parents. I weighed in on the birds' side.

Comment: @marky you are right about alien psyches though. House sparrows pair for life. Yet they have lots of extra-pair and extra-flock sex! And if a sparrow grieves for a dead partner, it does not grieve for long. A new pair bond forms almost immediately with the first unattached sparrow to arrive. (Same-sex pairs are not unknown).

Comment: You may want to check out Tim Birkhead's book "[Bird Sense](https://www.amazon.com/Bird-Sense-What-Its-Like/dp/1620401894)" if you're interested in more information about what a bird might sense and think.

Answer (score 2):

My bird appears to find that [pinfeathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_feather) on top of the head are itchy but painful if manipulated.

There is a lot of work preening and repairing feathers with your tounge.

Flying is *hard work*.  Do you use a bicycle or do any sports? You could use that feeling of tiredness and wishing you were there already.

What kind of bird? As prey animals many birds would have mental state that reflects being on alert and ready to flee at any unexpected sensev this would seem opressively paranoid and cowardly to a human.

Comment: At the instinctive level *humans* are prey animals, which is why we startle at shadows and small harmless creatures. Consciousness is too slow; ready to flee first, think after.

Comment: @nigel222 if you hang around some pettowners discussion forums or read books on parrot ownership, you will see discussion on how the psycology of parrots (prey animals) is different from humans, dogs, cats (preditors).  Your interpretation that we startle sometimes too is completely neglecting the real difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Larger birds of prey, hunters with shotguns, heavy winds, breeze-less air, air-pollution, eating worms, difficulty communicating (beautiful songs but no words), fleas,

and worst of all, having to watch all the flightless humans, who can't understand the happiness of a carefree life.

Anyone planning to write from a bird's point of view, should read the first few chapters of Richard Bach's Jonathan Livingston Seagull.  Great writing about the sensation of flight.

Comment: Oh yes, fleas. Another pointer to avian intelligence. Crows have been observed fumigating themselves using cigarette butts dropped by people. Users of found fire.

Comment: No words? Maybe, but listen to a conversation in Chinese first. It's a tonal language.

Answer (score 0):

A bird, like most animals and especially non-mammals, are heavily controlled by their instinct, and does not reflect, communicate or learn without stimulus. It would most likely have no other care in the world than the current instinctual task. So the most likely answer to what the bird might be thinking is "Where is food? I need food for my babies (or myself)." or "I need to find a partner!"
Your characters could philosophy over what free will is, or question whether the bird can be happy in general without being rewarded. :)

Comment: I had to downvote that for the mammalian superiority comment. Find out about Alex the parrot. Find out about the short list of species that make tools to solve problems: it includes birds. Above all **open your eyes**.  The rooks living in a tree near me take to the air in gales. Why? Practicing?  Having fun?  It's not courtship and it's not finding food.

Comment: Didn't want to end on a grim note but Ravens are learning to kill sheep by working in coordinated groups. They are not hunters by nature,  the results are ugly and to human sensibilities, cruel. What was the last species to learn to hunt like this? Possibly, *homo sapiens*. I don't imagine our ancestors made clean quick kills either.

Comment: Well, fire ants (here in Texas) work in groups to kill cattle and the occasional unattended elderly person.  Common ravens get [half their calories by predation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_raven#Diet)—they *are* hunters by nature.

Comment: @nigel222 Animal intelligence mechanisms are as varied as its possessors. While I agree that suggesting intelligence (over instinct) is more often a mammal trait is unwarranted, I didn't read Stri's answer as intending bias that way. The salient point made here, and why I upvoted, is that a wild bird likely is blissfully unaware of the things humans might consider "unpleasant." They may even be victims of activity that we characterize as negative for them (such as habitat loss), yet they do _(may?)_ not have the level of awareness needed to perceive such cause and effect.

Answer (score 0):

If birds are intelligent enough ( and I am sure that some are) then the greatest frustration must surely be not having hands. They work miracles with one claw and a beak....

Not a frustration but a difference. A bird could not fly if it could not react far faster than a human. My theory ( unprovable) is that bird consciousness works maybe ten times faster than ours. I wonder if an hour to a bird is like a day to a human, in which case a winter night must be something truly terrifying to a bird. There again,  it might mean that parrots live for 600 years subjectively.

Comment: My impression is that when a parrot engages “thinking” mode, it is much *slower* than the dumber instinctive behavior.  Action and consequence, choices to be made, understand what will happen *if*: it takes a few seconds to percolate.  It makes sense that the small brain uses more serial rather than parallel processing.

Comment: Think about your own special skills as a biped built as an unstable inverted pendulum: an alien might suppose your conciousness works much faster in order to be able to ride a bicycle!  **no**, it is completely unconcious and you *can’t* think about it.

Comment: As for hands, some birds feet (such as my pet’s zygodactyl arrangement) makes for a **very good** hand.  The drawback is only using one as a hand.

Comment: @JDlugosz I should have emphasized hand**s** plural. I'm quite aware that some bird's claws are far more, er, dextrous, than they might appear, but the bird can use only one of them -- it has to stand on the other.

Comment: @JDlugosz agree about not thinking about reflexive actions, but a bird's reflexes are of aerodynamic necessity far quicker than ours, and perhaps its time sense likewise? Also, slow down birdsong and you discover that sequences we hear as mere trills are in fact much more complex patterns of melody and rhythm. Presumably the bird can perceive these patterns, which we can't unless we record and play back at reduced speed.

Comment: «slow down birdsong and you discover that sequences we hear as mere trills are in fact much more complex patterns of melody and rhythm» so is human laughter.  If you look at human speech in a spectrum analysis view you’ll see that individial phonoms are quite complex, and the details are impossible to control conciously.  *fast* pattern processing, like being able to follow a single voice in a noisy crowd or recognising faces in an wierd painting of fruit, is **un**concious.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of things that could be unpleasant about being a bird.

1) being out in the weather all the time. The rain, the cold, the extreme heat, the wind. They might be built to withstand it, but it still doesn't mean that it's pleasant for them. Also being exposed to man-made pollution in the air, waterways, and ground.

2) the fact that they're ruled by instinct

A) fight or flight. And depending on the particular bird in question, they might not have the best ability to fight back.

B) Limited understanding of the universe (they're called "bird brains" for a reason!)

C) Predator or prey. Consider having to eat raw meat... of another type of bird, or raw fish! Consider another bird dive bombing you!

3) Insects. They may eat insects, but in turn insects crawl in their feathers and eat them

4) Bird-only diseases

5) Getting caught and being kept as a pet for the rest of one's life.

6) CONSTANT maintenance. Feathers needs to preened constantly otherwise they won't work. A dirty bird can't fly as effectively. This is why they take many baths a day (even in dry climates, they'll take a bath of dust).

7) Sore muscles because you have to to fly away at a moment's notice, or from having to fly long distances for the winter (migration), only to have to repeat the cycle to fly back from whence you came.

8) Disappearing habitat. Can you imagine leaving for vacation and your home was gone when you got back? Also the fact that man moves your house. The last 4 generations were raised here, but the homeowner wanted to get a different birdhouse, and so your family home is gone without a trace.

Comment: Unpleasantness is relative. If your physiology is that of a bird, insects or raw meat may be wonderful. A limited understanding of something does not equate to lack of happiness or joy -- dogs oft appear cheerful without knowledge of economics or mathematics. Perhaps preening feathers is pleasant. Would being kept as a pet necessarily be unpleasant (free food)? If you were a bird in possession of your human memory and cognition, perhaps some of these would apply. But the question was about sensing a wild bird's emotional state or sense of well being, in which case I feel many do not.